# delete from multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of users
user id

```
3 ,Frank
4 ,Steve
5 ,Joe
```

and a table of roles where column 1 is id of users in above table:

```
1, billing
3, Admin
2, Admin
4, user
5, billing
```

as you can see users 1 and 2 has been orphaned, and there is no user with id of 2.  how can i delete this entry from the roles table?  there could be dozens of entries in roles that dont have a user.

will this work?

```
 DELETE from roles,users where roles.userId!==users.userId
```

Comment: You might be able to use Foreign Key constraints

Comment: But I'd also suggest normalising your data. Create a Roles table with each role and a roleid then make a lookup up table which links userid to roleid.

Comment: As AeroX said, you could set options like "Cascade delete" with your FK declaration. But again, in real-life applications, cascade is considered a bit risky. It will be better to split it into 2 statements.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to delete from `users` if the user is not there.  So you can just do:

```
delete r from roles r
    where not exists (select 1 from users u where u.userId = r.userId);
```

As mentioned in a comment, if you declared the `roles.userId` value to be a foreign key reference, then the database would not let this happen.  After the data is fixed, you can do:

```
alter table roles add constraint foreign key (userId) references user(userId);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELETE FROM roles WHERE id NOT IN (SELECT id FROM users)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Q: Will this work?**

**A:** Close, but no cigar. No, the statement in the question won't perform the specified operation.

First, write a query to identify the orphaned rows. An anti-join pattern is a common approach (though there are several other workable approaches):

```
SELECT r.*
  FROM `roles` r
  LEFT
  JOIN `user` u 
    ON u.id = r.user_id
 WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

This uses an "outer" join, to return *all* rows from `roles`, along with matching rows from `user`. If no matching row is found in `user`, the columns from the `user` table will be returned as NULL. Given the equality comparison in the join predicate (ON clause), we know that all matching rows will have a non-NULL value for `u.id`. The "trick" is the predicate in the WHERE clause that excludes all rows that found a match, so we are left with rows in `roles` that don't have a matching row in `users`

(If you want to examine the rows that will be deleted and/or create a "backup" of those rows, this query gives you that.)

Next, convert the `SELECT` statement into a `DELETE` statement. For this particular statement, it's very straightforward with MySQL. The only change required is to replace the `SELECT` keyword with the `DELETE` keyword:

```
DELETE r.*
  FROM `roles` r
  LEFT
  JOIN `user` u 
    ON u.id = r.user_id
 WHERE u.id IS NULL
```

This is an example of just one of several workable approaches.